# String with unicode doesn't match on new XCode UI Test and the test fails

Tags: objective-c, unicode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I was making some UI Tests using the new XCode 7. How my app uses Notification, on first use iOS automatically ask '"MyApp" Would Like to Send You Notifications'.

When I record the test, XCode write these lines below:

```
- (void)testFirstUse {
    [XCUIDevice sharedDevice].orientation = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;

    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    [app.alerts[@"\U201cMyApp\U201d Would Like to Send You Notifications"].collectionViews.buttons[@"OK"] tap];
    [app.tables/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.staticTexts[@"United States"]/*[[".cells.staticTexts[@\"United States\"]",".staticTexts[@\"United States\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/ tap];
    [app.navigationBars[@"Select a Country"].buttons[@"Next"] tap];

}
```

Note that XCode puts the unicode instead of quotes signal on MyApp name.
When a run the test fails with error "No matches found for alert".

I tried change the unicode to quote signal but it also doesn't work.

Is it clear?
Had someone this same issue?

**[Update]**
I have two issue on this code

1- There is a bug on message with unicodes generated by XCode

2- Test fails after tap on Alerts showed by system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one work around for avoid crashing after dismissing a system alert:

I changed this line

```
[app.alerts[@"\U201cMyApp\U201d Would Like to Send You Notifications"].collectionViews.buttons[@"OK"] tap];
```

to

```
XCUIElement *alert = app.alerts[@"\U0000201cMyApp\U0000201d Would Like to Send You Notifications"].collectionViews.buttons[@"OK"];    
if ([alert exists]) {
    [alert tap];
}
```

I made two changes

- the four 0000 on unicodes in order to avoid build failed
- And the a validation before tap on alert to avoid test failed

Comment: This still crashes for me if the alert is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You can acknowledge the alert by directly accessing the `alert.element` and tapping the "OK" button via the collection view.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
// trigger location permission dialog

app.alerts.element.collectionViews.buttons["Allow"].tap()
```

However, Xcode 7 (and Xcode 7.1 Beta) will crash after successfully dismissing the alert. I've opened a [bug report with Apple](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4979891669827584) and encourage all those experiencing the problem to duplicate it.

Comment: Now i got the problem tks @Joe Masilotti. But I noticed that it's happening only with Alerts launched by iOS.

Comment: Correct, @Salmo. You can dismiss your own `UIAlertView`s and `UIAlertController`s without issue.

Comment: I just found one work around. I posted it below. But I will also open one issue on Apple like u did.

Answer (score 1):

The format of unicode characters generated by xcode is wrong so it is xcode bug. As a temporary workaround you could replace

```
[app.alerts[@"\U201cMyApp\U201d Would Like to Send You Notifications"].collectionViews.buttons[@"OK"] tap];
```

with

```
[app.alerts[@"\u201cMyApp\u201d Would Like to Send You Notifications"].collectionViews.buttons[@"OK"] tap];
```

i.e. all **\U** on **\u**